# Select box fails to fetch option value with spaces

Tags: javascript, html

I have a select box which fetches the values from the database.the options in the database are:

1.Rice
2.Cooking Oil

the select box shows the exact values from the database but not for the one with spacing

Below is my code 
var html_code = ''+i+'';

```
<?php while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
var op_val = "<?php echo $row['ITEM_NAME'];?>";
 var opt_id = "<?php echo $row['ITEM_NAME'];?>";
 options += "<option value ="+opt_id+">"+op_val+"</option>";
 <?php endwhile;?>

 html_code += "<td><select onchange='check_duplicate()' class='form-control border-input' id='id' name='id[]' required><option value=''> -- Select Item --</option> "+options+" </select></td>";
```

when I check on the HTML it shows out

```
<option value="Cooking" oil="">Cooking Oil</option>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with below code:

```
<?php while($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result)):; ?>
var op_val = "<?php echo $row['ITEM_NAME'];?>";
 var opt_id = "<?php echo $row['ITEM_NAME'];?>";
 options += "<option value ='"+opt_id+"'>"+op_val+"</option>";
 <?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

just put value in quote from option **value ="+opt_id+" to option value ='"+opt_id+"'** and all should be fine, actually in your current code, space is treated as next attribute.